# how to include one jsp page in another jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, jspinclude

### terms_span.jsp

```
            <jsp:include page="/includes/inc_terms_span.jsp">
                <jsp:param name="list" value="true" />

            </jsp:include>
```

### inc_term_span.jsp

```
<%String showaslist = request.getParameter("list"); System.out.println("show list? "+showaslist); 
    if(showaslist!=null && showaslist.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
%>

<p> Welcome to the page </p>

else
{%>

<p> error in the connection </p>
<%}%>
```

Comment: Are you sharing your knowledge by answering your own question?

Comment: I want to call inc_term_span.jsp in terms_span.jsp page. but i cant make a call

Comment: Define "I can't". What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: when i make a call to terms_span.jsp It doesn't load the inc_term_span.jsp page

Comment: The JSP file name is written wrong.

Comment: +1 for Christian St.: inc_terms_span != inc_term_span

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd block of code is a bit of a mess of scriptlet tags.

At the start you have

```
<%String ...
```

I'm not certain, but you might need a gap between the scriptlet tag and the java:

```
<%
  String ...
```

Right after the `else` theres a closing tag `%>` without a matching `<%`

Try tidying that up and see where you get...

Comment: I tried it but still i cant see the content in 2nd block. It shows application error

Comment: @user2916626, See my answer to try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Following NickJ's answer, I see 2 further mistakes made.

1. The file name `inc_terms_span.jsp` you want to include is (maybe) written wrong, because you show us the content of `inc_term_span.jsp`.
2. At the line `if(showaslist!=null && showaslist.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){` there's an opening bracket `{`, but you never close it before the `else`.

Try this code to fix it:

```
<%
String showaslist = request.getParameter("list"); 
System.out.println("show list? " + showaslist); 
if(showaslist != null && showaslist.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
%>

<p> Welcome to the page </p>

<%}
else
{%>

<p> error in the connection </p>

<%}%>
```